# Inserting color code from OpenStreetMap to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, openstreetmap, color

I have a color code from OpenStreetMap.

How do I insert this code of color to ArcMap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little vague, but I assume you mean you have hex color codes.  ArcMap does not support hex codes, so you'll have to convert them to RGB or CMYK.

You can use a color converter tool like this one: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm